# Rails how to split into array ActiveRecord AssociationRelation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Let's say I've got query which fetches 2 types of posts in random order:

```
@posts = @customer.posts.where("name ? = OR name ? =", "Google", "Yahoo")
```

This returns me `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` object with given posts names
And I want to output them in this format:

```
output = [
    # here just google posts,
    # here just yahoo posts
]
```

how can i select specific post inside array?

```
Google | Yahoo
Test   | Test yahoo
Test   | Test yahoo
Test   | Test yahoo
Test   | Test yahoo
Test   | Test yahoo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you are asking but if you want to order the results so that google is before yahoo you could try something like:

```
@posts = @customer.posts.where(name: ["google", "yahoo"]).order(:name)
```

if you want to convert to an array you could use pluck for example

```
@posts = @customer.posts.where(name: ["google", "yahoo"]).order(:name).pluck([:name,:id])
```

Alternativley - (guessing as your question is not so clear)

```
@posts = [
  @customer.posts.where(name:"google").pluck( [:fields, :you, :want]),
  @customer.posts.where(name:"yahoo").pluck( [:fields, :you, :want])
]
```

(you can then re-factor into a helper)

Comment: and how can I put the results inside array?

Comment: and how do i differentiate Google and Yahoo posts at the end as it returns me an array of names?

Comment: you can put whatever fields you need in the pluck statement,

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear from the question, but you code use the `group_by` to split the returned posts by name. For example:

```
@posts = @customer.posts.where("name ? = OR name ? =", "Google", "Yahoo").group_by(&:name)

@posts.each do |name, posts|
  puts name
  puts posts.count
end
```

Does that answer the question?

Comment: The problem is not with query, I want to put the results inside array as shown below: 0's index fill in with Google posts, 1's index fill in with Yahoo posts

Comment: So I think group_by should do the trick. You can iterate over the results without referencing the key eg:

@posts.each { |_,posts| puts posts }

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could just order the result by name:

```
@posts = @customer.posts.where("name ? = OR name ? =", "Google", "Yahoo").order(name: :asc)
```